# Keras-Tuner default value meaning

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-tuner

Really simple question, when using keras-tuner and searching for the best set of hyperparameters there are a range of types to search for, so for simplicity let's say I'm using `hp.Int()`, now I can set a `minimum`, a `maximum` and a `default` value for this. My question is where does default value come into play? If we're searching for the best possible combination, why a default value (I know the Bayesian search does not actually try all possible combinations so I have a feeling it can come into play here).

Comment: Please check [this](https://keras.io/api/keras_tuner/hyperparameters/#int-method) reference for detailed understanding in this.

Comment: Where is the detailed understanding? I checked this page before and it only states what it means, but not how it's used. What I'm asking is: when searching for the bests et of hyperparameters, where does a default value come into play when you are searching through several values of units for instance

Comment: Okay, `Default` value means base value or min_value where it starts searching for the best hyperparameters. If `Default` is None or not defined, it will consider min_value as the default value.

Comment: So when you specify both, when is the default value used instead of the min value?